# decode Javascript For loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I found this sample code but want to see how I can rewrite this using separate statements, ie. need to figure out the correct syntax

```
//Create the random data
   for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
     var my_object = {};
     my_object.key = i;
     my_object.country = getRandomCountry();
     my_object.value = createRandomValue;
     data.push(my_object);
   }
```

I tried

```
var my_object = {};
my_object(key[0]) = 0;
my_object(country[0]) = "GB";
my_object(value[0]) = 123;
my_object(key[1]) = 1;
my_object(country[1]) = "US";
my_object(value[1]) = 133;
```

but this doesn't work, how can the array be created/populated without the `for` loop ?

Answer (score 1):

Your loop actually do this. It creates an object in each operation, populates it and then push into the array. In your case: 2 times.

```
var data = [];

// Here starts
var my_object = {};
my_object.key = 0;
my_object.country = getRandomCountry();
my_object.value = createRandomValue;

data.push(my_object);

my_object = {};
my_object.key = 1;
my_object.country = getRandomCountry();
my_object.value = createRandomValue;

data.push(my_object);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the bracket notation as [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors),

> ```
> object.property    // dot notation
> object['property'] // bracket notation
> ```

```
var array = [],
    my_object;

my_object = {}
my_object[key[0]] = 0;
my_object[country[0]] = "GB";
my_object[value[0]] = 123;
array.push(my_object);

my_object = {}
my_object[key[1]] = 1;
my_object[country[1]] = "US";
my_object[value[1]] = 133;
array.push(my_object);
```